# Has Microsoft published any info on license upgrades from Visual Studio 2013 (no MSDN) to 2015?

Tags: visual-studio

Microsoft has published pricing on new purchases or upgrades from VS2013 *with MSDN*, but I haven't yet found any info covering upgrades from VS2013 which were purchased *without* MSDN e.g. VS 2013 Professional.

In my specific case, I want to upgrade from Visual Studio 2013 Professional to 2015 Professional. My only option appears to be purchasing 2015 *with* MSDN, with no consideration from my existing 2013 license.  Am I overlooking something?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it't about licensing, not programming.

Comment: Related, I am working on a contract that requires VS2015. Prime Software Global is a Microsoft Partner and reseller. It offers [Visual Studio Professional 2015](https://primeswg.com/product/visual-studio-professional-2015/) for $99 USD. Prime Software Global also accepts [Amazon Pay](https://pay.amazon.com/), so you don't have to share your credit card with a third party (if you have an Amazon account). You also get the ISO download link and product key immediately. The company's product page says, *"This is the Full version with Worldwide Lifetime License"*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Overview of Visual Studio 2015 Products](https://www.visualstudio.com/products/vs-2015-product-editions) page claims it is possible to purchase VS2015 Professional without MSDN, but *really* hides it well:

> **Visual Studio 2015 product offerings**
>
> - Visual Studio Community
> - Visual Studio Professional with MSDN
> - Visual Studio Enterprise with MSDN
>
> **Additional offerings**
>
> Visual Studio Community 2015, Visual Studio Professional with MSDN, and Visual Studio Enterprise with MSDN are the primary offerings in the Visual Studio 2015 lineup. Additional offerings include<sup>5</sup>
>
> Visual Studio Express 2015<sup>4</sup> editions
>
> Visual Studio Test Professional with MSDN
>
> Visual Studio Team Foundation Server 2015
>
> MSDN Platforms

And way down at the bottom of that page:

> 5. Visual Studio Professional 2015 standalone license, for customers interested in a non-subscription, IDE-only option

---

However, clicking through to [Buy Visual Studio and MSDN subscriptions](https://www.visualstudio.com/products/how-to-buy-vs) gives a better answer to your question:

> Visual Studio Professional 2015 is now sold month-to-month as part of Visual Studio Online, just choose the Professional level after you set up billing on your Visual Studio Online account.
>
> **Starting September 1, 2015, you can also purchase Visual Studio Professional 2015 through the Microsoft Store or through software resellers.**

So... all you need to do is wait.

Whether reduced upgrade pricing will be available for this edition does not appear to be answered yet though.

Comment: I have already downloaded/installed it under an evaluation license. With 86 days 'til expiry, I guess (hope) I will be able to buy a license before the trial runs out.

Answer (score 8):

### Update 2

I chatted with a Microsoft specialist. There is no upgrade pricing at this time and no upgrade pricing in the future, "that they are aware of".

### Update 1

Visual Studio 2015 Professional stand alone is now [available](http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msusa/en_US/pdp/Visual-Studio-Professional-2015/productID.323825200) for $499. No word on upgrade pricing yet.

### Original

It is now September 1st and the stand alone Visual Studio 2015 Professional is still not available.

I chatted with a Microsoft specialist. She confirmed that the stand alone Visual Studio 2015 Professional is not available and she did not have a release date.

The [Buy Visual Studio and MSDN subscriptions](https://www.visualstudio.com/products/how-to-buy-vs) page now lists the following:

> Please note: purchases through the Microsoft Store In some markets will show prior version products (Visual Studio Ultimate with MSDN, Visual Studio Professional 2013), but are being updated through the **end of October 2015**. Please purchase Visual Studio Ultimate with MSDN or Visual Studio Premium with MSDN to get Visual Studio Enterprise with MSDN. Please wait to purchase Visual Studio Professional 2015 until it is available; purchasing Visual Studio 2013 will not entitle you to an upgrade to Visual Studio Professional 2015.